# How to make dropdown list with Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was searching whole internet but that didn't help me to resolve issue.
With this code below I'm encountering 'Uncaught ReferenceError: VueSelect is not defined'
What's wrong with the code?

```
        var productForm = Vue.createApp ({
            data: function() {
                return {
                    product: {
                        sku: 0,
                        name: 'asdf',
                        price: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        
        productForm.component('custom-form', {
            props: ['value', 'options'],
            template: `
                <label>SKU<input type="text" :value=this.sku></label>
                <label>Name<input type="text" :value=this.name></label>
                <label>Price<input type="text" :value=this.price></label>
                <vue-select :options="options" label="option"
                  ></vue-select>
            ` ,
            
            data: function() {
                return {
                    sku: 0,
                    name: 'asdf',
                    price: 0,
                    options: [
                        { option: "Size" },
                        { option: "Weight" },
                        { option: "Dimensions" }
                    ]
                }
            }
        })
        
        const vm = productForm.mount('#product_form')
        vm.component('vue-select', VueSelect )
```

Comment: It says VueSelect is not defined, you have to first define/import VueSelect before you can use it. Where do you define your imports?

Comment: For learning purposes I'm just using '<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>' and no imports/exports and npms.

Comment: VueSelect is not a native Vue component, you have to add it first. If you are using a cdn add `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@3.13.2/dist/vue-select.js"></script> `below your `<script src="unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>`

Comment: After adding your mentioned script line, the console throws me following message: Uncaught TypeError: vm.component is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I managed successfully to do following without VueSelect:

```
var productForm = Vue.createApp ({})

        productForm.component('custom-form', {
                template: `
                <label>SKU<input type="text" v-model="this.product.sku"></label>
                <label>Name<input type="text" v-model="this.product.name"></label>
                <label>Price<input type="text" v-model="this.product.price"></label>
                <label>Attributes<select v-model="selected">
                    <option 
                        v-for="item in options" 
                        >{{item}}
                    </option>
                </select></label>
                ` ,
            
            data: function() {
                return {
                    product: {
                        sku: 0,
                        name: 'asdf',
                        price: 0
                    },
                    options: ['Size', 'Weight', 'Dimensions'],
                    selected: 'Size'
                }
            }
        })
       
        productForm.mount('#product_form')
```